# Git push to heroku and codebase at the same time

Tags: git, heroku

I have a "Heroku" and "Codebase" Repository and every time i push, it updates "Heroku" only. How do i add "Codebase" Repository into my git config and update both of them? should i use 
`git remote add alt name git@codebasehq.com:myproject.git` I tried 'push' and 'push origin' master, also noticed on my: `git config -e` there was no Code base path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first you should also add the other repository by doing:

```
$ git remote add alt-name git@codebasehq.com:myproject.git
```

However [`git-push`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) only pushes to one repo at a time, but you can always do:

```
$ git push origin && git push alt-name
```

If you want to do it an a single command, you can edit the project's git configuration, located in `.git/config` and add this:

```
[alias]
  push-all = !git push origin && git push alt-name
```

then you can just do a `$ git push-all` everytime you want to push to both repositories.